# nginx - Serve Single URL with Absolute FIle Path

Tags: nginx

I have a website that's getting a ton of traffic to a single url.

https://www.awebsite.com/some/really/long/search-friendly/url/my-url.html

I want to serve this, and only this url statically with nginx. The static html file lives at /my/html-files/myfile.html, with the correct permissions.

I DO NOT want this url to be affected:

https://www.awebsite.com/some/really/long/search-friendly/url/some-other-url.html

I've tried...

```
location = /some/really/long/search-friendly/url/myfile.html {
    alias /my/html-files/myfile.html;
}
```

and...

```
location = /some/really/long/search-friendly/url/myfile.html {
    root /my/html-files/myfile.html;
}
```

and...

```
location = /some/really/long/search-friendly/url/myfile.html {
    root /my/html-files/;
}
```

I can't get anything to work. Please help! Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out this is working in Chrome and Opera.

```
location = /some/really/long/search-friendly/url/myfile.html {
    alias /my/html-files/myfile.html;
}
```

For whatever reason, in Firefox, I'm constantly redirected to https://www.awebsite.com/some/really/long/search-friendly/url/my-url.html/. So Confused as to why this is happening only in FF, but, I'll take it for now.

Comment: As you've noted, the `alias` option is a working solution. Have you cleared the FF browser's cache?

Comment: I thought shift-R was a hard refresh in FF. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: I think you mean Ctrl-R (which is the same as F5) and does not override the cache. You would need to use Ctrl-Shift-R (or Ctrl-F5) to override the cache.

Comment: Because it was a redirect that was cached, I had to go into Preferences and manually clear the cache, restart FF and it started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is working in Chrome and Opera.

```
location = /some/really/long/search-friendly/url/myfile.html {
    alias /my/html-files/myfile.html;
}
```

If it's not, see comments; it could be a browser caching problem.

[Nginx documentation for `alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)